# django-allauth Google login not working on iOS

Tags: django, authentication, django-allauth, permission-denied, google-signin

I'm building a PWA with django and have this issue with django-allauth Google login. Everything works well on a Windows PC with Chrome and Edge. But when trying to login with Google on iOS devices, I get the social network login failure with code: 'unknown', exception: 'PermissionDenied()'

Any ideas what could be the reason or where to search for it?

**EDIT**

I tried to do some more debugging and got these errors (only on iOS devices!):

> Internal Server Error: /accounts/google/login/callback/ Traceback
> (most recent call last):   File
> "/home/kava/.virtualenvs/django3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/allauth/socialaccount/providers/oauth2/views.py",
> line 141, in dispatch
> login.state = SocialLogin.verify_and_unstash_state(   File "/home/kava/.virtualenvs/django3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/allauth/socialaccount/models.py",
> line 325, in verify_and_unstash_state
> raise PermissionDenied() django.core.exceptions.PermissionDenied

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem.

The error was caused by the line that follows `if "socialaccount_state" not in request.session:` in this function:

```
@classmethod
def verify_and_unstash_state(cls, request, verifier):
    if "socialaccount_state" not in request.session:
        raise PermissionDenied()
    state, verifier2 = request.session.pop("socialaccount_state")
    if verifier != verifier2:
        raise PermissionDenied()
    return state
```

So the problem was with the session data, more precisely, the 'socialaccount_state' was missing.

After Googling this issue in connection with iOS I found [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/django/comments/b9qp5a/session_data_lost_after_redirect_but_only_with/) thread.

I changed the [SESSION COOKIE_SAMESITE](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#std:setting-SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE) and [CSRF_COOKIE_SAMESITE](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#csrf-cookie-samesite) to None as suggested there and it works!

Btw, if 'None' was between apostrophes, it didn't work on iOS 12 devices.

Comment: Thanks for this! saved me so much time :)